# what flavors are lost in general cooking that arent lost cooking sous vide?

Tags: sous-vide

And when I saw General cooking I mean pan searing, roasting, baking, braising, stewing, grilling, etc.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question because most of the cooking techniques you identify result in flavor gain.  Further, sous vide is generally seen more as a way to manipulate texture, rather than flavor.

Comment: In several websites, I've read that the reason Sous vide is so superior is because flavors aren't lost. Now I know other cooking methods improve or add flavor, but I'm just asking about sous vide, and I've never anything about texture.